# Python: Heapify a list of tuples (Dijkstra's Algo)

Tags: python, list, tuples, heap, dijkstra

Here is my code for Dijkstra's Algorithm.
I have declared a "Vertex" class and a "Graph" class.
I am using heapq module and heapifying the list "unvisitedQueue" of tuples. But even then an error shows up saying " TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'Vertex' and 'Vertex' " even when "v.getDistance()" returns either 0 or float('inf').

```
import heapq

class Vertex:
    def __init__(self, node):
        self.id = node
        self.adjacent = {}
        self.previous = None
        self.distance = float('inf')
    
    def addNeighbor(self, neighbor, weight = 0):
        self.adjacent[neighbor] = weight
    
    def getConnections(self):
        return self.adjacent.keys()
    
    def getVertex_ID(self):
        return self.id
    
    def getWeight(self, neighbor):
        return self.adjacent[neighbor]

    def setDistance(self, dist):
        self.distance = dist

    def getDistance(self):
        return self.distance

    def setPrevious(self, prev):
        self.previous = prev

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id) + "adjacent : " + str([x.id for x in self.adjacent])
    
class Graph:
    def __init__(self):
        self.vertDictionary = {}
        self.numVertices = 0
    
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.vertDictionary.values())
    
    def addVertex(self, node):
        self.numVertices += 1
        newVertex = Vertex(node)
        self.vertDictionary[node] = newVertex
        return newVertex
    
    def getVertex(self, node):
        if node in self.vertDictionary:
            return self.vertDictionary[node]
        else:
            return None
    
    def addEdge(self, frm, to, cost = 0):
        if frm not in self.vertDictionary:
            self.addVertex(frm)
        if to not in self.vertDictionary:
            self.addVertex(to)
        self.vertDictionary[frm].addNeighbor(self.vertDictionary[to], cost)
        
        self.vertDictionary[to].addNeighbor(self.vertDictionary[frm], cost)
    
    def getVertices(self):
        return self.vertDictionary.keys()
    
    def setPrevious(self, current):
        self.previous = current
    
    def getPrevious(self):
        return self.previous
    
    def getEdges(self):
        edges = []
        for v in G:
            for w in v.getConnections():
                v_id = v.getVertex_ID()
                w_id = w.getVertex_ID()
                edges.append((v_id, w_id, v.getWeight(w)))
        return edges
def Dijkstra(G, s):
    source = G.getVertex(s)
    source.setDistance(0)
    visited = {}
    unvisitedQueue = [(v.getDistance(), v) for v in G]
    heapq.heapify(unvisitedQueue)
    while len(unvisitedQueue):
        uv = heapq.heappop(unvisitedQueue)
        currVert = uv[1]
        visited[currVert] = True
        for nbr in currVert.getConnections():
            if currVert.getDistance() + currVert.getWeight(nbr) < nbr.getDistance():
                nbr.setDistance(currVert.getDistance() + currVert.getWeight(nbr))
                print("Updated: Current = %s Neighbour = %s New Distance = %s" %(currVert.getVertex_ID(), nbr.getVertex_ID(), nbr.getDistance()))
            else:
                print("Not Updated: Current = %s Neighbour = %s Distance = %s" %(currVert.getVertex_ID(), nbr.getVertex_ID(), nbr.getDistance()))
        while len(unvisitedQueue):
            heapq.heappop(unvisitedQueue)
        unvisitedQueue = [(v.getDistance(), v) for v in G if v not in visited]
        heapq.heapify(unvisitedQueue)
    for v in G:
        print(source.getVertex_ID(), "to", v.getVertex_ID(), "-->", v.getDistance())
```

ERROR -->

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Python\Final 450\Graph\Dijkstra's_Algo.py", line 124, in <module>
    print(Dijkstra(G, "a"))
  File "d:\Python\Final 450\Graph\Dijkstra's_Algo.py", line 86, in Dijkstra 
    heapq.heapify(unvisitedQueue)
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'Vertex' and 'Vertex'
```

Comment: where is the `Vertex` declaration? Please share it.

Comment: "" TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'Vertex' and 'Vertex' " even when "v.getDistance()" returns either 0 or float('inf')." In your own words, what is your understanding of how Python compares two tuples? In particular, what will happen if the first value of each tuple is equal? In your own words, what is the intended logic for comparing and ordering vertices in the heap - what is the rule that tells you that one vertex is "smaller" than another and thus belongs "on top" in a min heap?

Comment: When comparing a tuple if first value is equal, then it tries to use the second value to compare, which in your case is a vertex. In your heap you should store a tuple that could have a unique number at the second param, like an index, since when the distance is the same, you can get any vertex.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) The images you have included doesn't tell us anything that your text summary doesn't. It also [isn't complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough). You should copy and paste the entire traceback, paste it in, and format it as code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is happening because tuples are compared lexicographically. If two distances are the same, the comparison moves on to the `Vertex` objects themselves.

Two solutions readily come to mind. The first is simply to add a unique index to the tuple before the `Vertex` but after the distance. This is easy, and would work even if you didn't have access to the `Vertex` class:

```
unvisitedQueue = [(v.getDistance(), i, v) for i, v in enumerate(G) if v not in visited]
```

The second option is to modify `Vertex` to have a `__lt__` magic method:

```
def __lt__(self, other):
    return self.getDistance() < other.getDistance()
```

This is nice because you can heapify more directly now:

```
unvisitedQueue = [v for v in G if v not in visited]
```

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode should be O(N log N) comparisons vs O(N). You won't notice the difference

Comment: And all you're saving is the extra function call. The comparisons themselves are cheaper and get done either way. Now it's N log N calls to getDistance instead of N calls to getDistance followed by N log N calls to `tuple.__lt__`. This night actually speed it up. Premature optimization and all...

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode. I meant that creating the key takes O(N) calls to getDistance, while heapifying directly takes O(N log N) calls.

Comment: That did it and also I got it in my head. Thanks, man.